# Doctrine generating wrong INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I generated a MySQL database using Doctrine with Symfony and had to modify one table, by extracting two of its attributes and assign them to a new Entity.
The first entity is called "Area" and the second one is called "Formato".
Previously, when I wanted to create a new Area, I provided its id, name, width and height.
(As the application is designed in Spanish, width is called "ancho" and height is called "alto")
Now, with the new design, the idea is to provide its id, name, and FormatId.
Of course, there will be some Formats already inserted in the Format table, and Area will have FormatId as a foreign key to Formato.
So far it's not a complex thing to do, however, when I try to create a new Area, I receive an error:

```
AbstractMySQLDriver->convertException('An exception occurred while executing \'INSERT INTO areas (descripcion, nombre, idarea, ancho, alto, idmedio, idformato) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)\' with params ["", "Zilosoft Area7", "21626759324", null, null, "28545628", "1"]:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column \'ancho\' in \'field list\'', object(PDOException))
```

So, as you can see, the new `INSERT` statement is mixing up the old attributes with the new one, generating sort of a "mixed" or "merged" statement.

I've been searching over and over through the source files but can't understand how is this happening, as my `Entities` are all up to date, meaning by this that Area has a Format and not "ancho" nor "alto", and Formato is a separated Entity with "ancho" and "alto" inside it.

Do you know if I should like "reset" or "clean cache" in Doctrine so that it generates the correct Insert statement?

By the way, formato is data taken from a combo box in a Twig template, and its loaded from the Formatos table.

Comment: Try clearing cache of your application. Previous files referencing the outdated entities sound like the issue.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewNolan for your answer. After trying clearing cache, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You're only missing the final step

So you updated your Entities to improve, update, or simply modify your data structure, however you MySQL database still has no idea you made those changes. The way to remedy that is by telling Doctrine to [update the schema](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-the-database-tables-schema). the way you do this is by running the following command on your machine:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

note that `--force` will try running the query directly. If you would rather run the queries yourself, you can use the `--dump-sql` option, which will print out all the queries you

Comment: I did what you said, but unfortunately now I receive this other error: {Fatal Compile Error: Cannot declare class QuieroAvisosBundle\Entity\Area, because the name is already in use}

Comment: This error can happen if the namespace specified in the class is not the right one (i.e. if you copy/pasted some other file and forgot to change the namespace). clearing the cache using `app/console cache:clear` at this point can also help.

Comment: Unfortunately @William Perron even though your advise makes sense, it didn't solve the problem either. I'm still getting the exact same error. I'm working with my colleague using SVN, that's the only way these files have been updated. No copy paste issued. I can't get why this entity can't be just updated instead of Doctrine attempting to create it as a new entity. In the past, when we had a similar issue, we had to create a new database and create a brand new project from scratch, which actually is the worst solution ever.

Comment: This is indeed very weird. There could be many different reasons why these problems are occuring: maybe it has to do with some change in svn, maybe it has to do with some config that hasn't been properly set or it could be a problem with the database just to name a few. At this point we are moving way out of scope of the original question, I suggest doing some more debugging on your end and post a separate question for that

Comment: I do agree. I'll do what you suggest. Thank you all for your answers and your time!

Comment: @WilliamPerron two words: you rule!